# Use PGO (The Postgres Operator) to deploy backup replica for existing server

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, postgres-operator

I have an existing (non-PGO) PostgreSQL server running in production (using AWS RDS).

Now, I would like to deploy a replica server for backup/archiving/analytics purposes in a separate cloud (e.g. GCP) and I've found PGO (The Postgres Operator) to be a promising tool for PostgreSQL deployment and management.

However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use PGO in order to set-up a replica slave for existing third-party non-PGO database server.

The PGO [does support multi-cluster federation](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.7.0/architecture/high-availability/multi-cluster-kubernetes/), but it looks like it needs a primary cluster operated by PGO as well.

Is there a way to use PGO to deploy backup replica for existing PostgreSQL server or should I better use some other solution?